# textclips in moviepy on google colab (imagemagick error)

Tags: imagemagick, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to add text to a moviepy video, but I'm having trouble getting imagemagick to work on google colab.

The code:

```
!apt install imagemagick
from moviepy.editor import TextClip
txtClip = TextClip('Cool effect',color='white',
 font="Amiri-Bold", kerning = 5, fontsize=100)
```

The error:

```
OSError: MoviePy Error: creation of None failed because 
of the following error:

[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'unset': 'unset'.

.This error can be due to the fact that ImageMagick is 
not installed on your computer, or (for Windows users) 
that you didn't specify the path to the ImageMagick 
binary in file conf.py, or that the path you specified 
is incorrect
```

research:

- [Not able to add Text Clip in Moviepy. Getting error related to Imagemagic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48578614/not-able-to-add-text-clip-in-moviepy-getting-error-related-to-imagemagic)
- [Getting error about ImageMagick With Python/MoviePy when I try add text clip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65136644/getting-error-about-imagemagick-with-python-moviepy-when-i-try-add-text-clip)

Attempt at resolving the issue:

Based on the error message, I started looking for the conf.py file.  I ran
`!find / -type d -name "conf.py"` but none of the files returned seemed to be under the subdirectory of imagemagick.

I also modified the policy.xml file under /etc/ImageMagick-6 by commenting out the line `<!--<policy domain="path" rights="none" pattern="@*"/>-->` but to no avail seemingly.

Any ideas??

Comment: After uncommenting that line in our policy.xml file you need to change `rights="none"` to `rights="read|write"`

Answer (score 3):

You need to run these to complete the moviepy and imagemagick setup on google colab

```
!pip install moviepy

!apt install imagemagick

!apt install libmagick++-dev

!cat /etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml | sed 's/none/read,write/g'> /etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. Check if this work for you: Install with:

> !apt install
> imagemagick

Then to fix the issue that it thinks ImageMagick is not installed use this:

> !cat /etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml | sed 's/none/read,write/g'>
> /etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).